# Unconsistent component size of map with bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am using google api to plot map. But map is going outside the frame.As shown below. Anyone knows what might be reason?

I am using bokeh 0.12.3[World View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoLdQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google made some underlying change that broke old versions of Bokeh (0.12.3 is quite old at this point). You will need to update to a recent version.